# Force scan files after taking photo

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

on api level 4 (android 1.6), after taking photo using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "NewPic.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

I'd like to look through all my photos thumbnails, but there is no my last photo thumbnail. It works perfectly on android 2.1.

If I connect device via USB to PC and then disconnect file will appear, after finished scanning. So how should I start that indexing?

I tried

```
mScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this);
mScanner.connect();
mScanner.scanFile(imageUri.getEncodedPath(), "*/*");
```

And end with this:

```
02-24 17:13:54.678: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(1320): IMediaScannerService.scanFile: /sdcard/NewPic2222.jpg mimeType: */*
02-24 17:13:54.688: VERBOSE/MediaProvider(1320): /sdcard volume ID: 1149784819
02-24 17:13:54.688: VERBOSE/MediaProvider(1320): key exists
```

**EDITED LATER**

I've got sth like this in other activity

```
mCursorThumbnails = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(mContentResolver, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, projection);
mCursorImages = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(mContentResolver, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection);
```

When I check count of first value I've got 13 elements, and on the second I've got 14. So the image has been added to mediascanner, but OS hasn't generated thumbnail for it. So how should I ask OS to create one?

Comment: you do call scanFile after you receive the  onMediaScannerConnected() don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after taking picture try calling insert() function of [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) passing the information about the picture.

```
public final Uri insert (Uri url, ContentValues values)
```

It will actually add the picture to the database and create picture's thumbnail image for you. It will also be added to the thumbnail database. Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks promising. I can't check if it's working, becouse I've already made hack for it, but I'll try it later.

Comment: you can check android camera app source code for reference. Specifically the ImageManager::addImage() function.

Comment: what should I add as value if I want to add an image?

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you **add** a file, let MediaStore Content Provider knows about it using the [sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) method

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(mediaFileAdded)));
```

For **deletion**, use:

```
getContentResolver().delete(uriOfMediaFileDeteled, null, null)
```

Main advantage: work with any mime type supported by MediaStore

In your case, do this in onActivityResultMethod (i.e.) after the photo has been successfuly taken

Comment: Great solution ! This should be the accepted answer. Simple, and it works.

Comment: What is `sendBroadcast` ?!!

Comment: @Yahya I just updated my answer with a link to sendBroadcast method. this method can be invoked on any activity as well (since activity is a context)

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
public static void scanFile(Context context, String path, String mimeType ) {
    Client client = new Client(path, mimeType);
    MediaScannerConnection connection =
            new MediaScannerConnection(context, client);
    client.connection = connection;
    connection.connect();
}

private static final class Client implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private final String path;
    private final String mimeType;
    MediaScannerConnection connection;

    public Client(String path, String mimeType) {
        this.path = path;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        connection.scanFile(path, mimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Then just call `scanFile(imageUri.getPath(), null)`.

Don't use encoded path and don't use `"*/*"` as a MIME type because `null` value makes scanner to determine MIME type automatically.

Comment: I believe that usage of MediaScanner is not the issue. I've edited first post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, long origId, int kind, BitmapFactory.Options options)
```

to force the creation of the thumbnail for an image.

Comment: does it now? (actually it requires level 5, which still makes it unusable for this problem)