# Android picture saved to SD card not showing in Gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard

Currently I have a program that takes pictures and saves them as a jpg on the top level of the sdcard, but its not appearing in the Gallery. Is there something I must do to make it happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to [call the MediaScanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) so that it knows your file exists:

```
File file; // = your file
String mimetype; // = your file's mimetype. MimeTypeMap may be useful.
MediaScanner.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{mimetype}, null);
```

Comment: Any example how to use this please? :)

Comment: Nevermind got it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107823/force-scan-files-after-taking-photo

Comment: What is `MediaScanner` for God sake?! , it should be `MediaScannerConnection` instead !

Comment: It should be something like this: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{file.getPath()}, null, null);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer. Working for me

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(finalFile)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is "overseeing" it...

Take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110571/371749