# Android App - How to save a bitmap drawing on canvas as image? Check code?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I tried to use the following codes to

1. Draw on canvas
2. Save the canvas on Image

*Problem - When I try to save the image, it shows a null pointer error and nothing is saved.*

Please help me to find the problem with the code or suggest me an alternative, which does excatly the same. Thanks in advance.

Code to draw on canvas:

```
package com.example.draw2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDrawView extends View {
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;

    public MyDrawView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
    return mBitmap;
    }



    public void clear(){
        mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.GREEN);
        invalidate();
        System.gc();

    }

}
```

Second code to save the canvas as image is in main activity.

I tried a few things and some part of the code is commented.

Since I am a beginner, I appreciate any advice

Second code MainActivity:

```
package com.example.draw2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    MyDrawView myDrawView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myDrawView = new MyDrawView(this, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);    
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {       
                //View content = myDrawView;

                //System.out.println(content);


                //Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                 boolean success = false;
                 if (!folder.exists()) 
                 {
                     success = folder.mkdirs();
                 }

                 System.out.println(success+"folder");

                 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sample.JPEG");

             if ( !file.exists() )
             {
                   try {
                    success = file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }

             System.out.println(success+"file");



             FileOutputStream ostream = null;
                try
                {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                System.out.println(ostream);

                Bitmap save = myDrawView.getBitmap();
                if(save == null) {
                    System.out.println("NULL bitmap save\n");
                }
                save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                   ostream.flush();
                    ostream.close();
                }catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find the code that takes the image to save it anywhere in your on click event! you created an empty file and then tried to read that empty file. Do you mean that you want us to provide you with these lines of code?

Comment: I am interested to know the mistakes in this code, and how can i improve it.

Comment: I tried the answer of JRowan down here and it worked for me. Are you saying that it didn't work for you?

Comment: your code do not draw!

Comment: It draws, i installed the above programs on samsung galaxy ace, and i am able to draw, but while saving it still shows me null error

Comment: I took exactly the same code it doesn't draw. are you sure you are not missing some code lines in the question?

Comment: it does, if so, it me post all the codes again as suggested my JRowan too

Comment: I have edited the latest code, but shows the same problem

Comment: @hasan - use the above codes it draws on canvas

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MyDrawView

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.LruCache;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDrawView extends View {
    public Bitmap  mBitmap;
    public Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;


    public MyDrawView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        //this.measure(100, 100);
        //this.layout(0, 0, 100, 100);
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
        this.buildDrawingCache();
       Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());   
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


    return bmp;
    }



    public void clear(){
        mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.GREEN);
        invalidate();
        System.gc();

    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    MyDrawView myDrawView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // myDrawView = new MyDrawView(this, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDrawView = (MyDrawView)findViewById(R.id.draw);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);    
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {       


                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                 boolean success = false;
                 if (!folder.exists()) 
                 {
                     success = folder.mkdirs();
                 }

                 System.out.println(success+"folder");

                 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sample.png");

             if ( !file.exists() )
             {
                   try {
                    success = file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }

             System.out.println(success+"file");



             FileOutputStream ostream = null;
                try
                {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                System.out.println(ostream);
                View targetView = myDrawView;

               // myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               //   Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap(myDrawView.getDrawingCache());
               //   myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                // copy this bitmap otherwise distroying the cache will destroy
                // the bitmap for the referencing drawable and you'll not
                // get the captured view
               //   Bitmap save = b1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
                //BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
                //canvasView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
               //   myDrawView.destroyDrawingCache();
               // Bitmap save = myDrawView.getBitmapFromMemCache("0");
               // myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               //Bitmap save = myDrawView.getDrawingCache(false);
                Bitmap well = myDrawView.getBitmap();
                Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Config.ARGB_8888);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                Canvas now = new Canvas(save);
                now.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,320,480), paint);
                now.drawBitmap(well, new Rect(0,0,well.getWidth(),well.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,320,480), null);

              // Canvas now = new Canvas(save);
               //myDrawView.layout(0, 0, 100, 100);
               //myDrawView.draw(now);
                if(save == null) {
                    System.out.println("NULL bitmap save\n");
                }
                save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                   //ostream.flush();
                    //ostream.close();
                }catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.example.draw2.MyDrawView 
    android:id ="@+id/draw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.example.draw2.MyDrawView>"
   <Button 
       android:id ="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="save"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ></Button>"

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your AndroidManifest.xml make sure you have

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.draw2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.draw2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you put up the logcat so i can see the details of the crash?

Comment: It doesn't crash, when i draw something on the app, and try to save it, it shows null.

Comment: I have incorporated ur suggestion, please check it doesn't work.

Comment: i just got in, sorry for the delay, give me a little bit im going to replicate your code in my IDE and let you know what the problem is

Comment: really quick i just noticed someting i just made a change

Comment: Thanks! Did you run it on mobile device, I doesn't throw an error on ide, but shows an error on mobile device. Although, I am not sure why it doesn't work for me, let me check if I am missing anything.

Comment: there you go, let me know if you got it

Comment: @JRowan your method is working fine. The canvas is saving in a .png format, but it is not showing in the gallery. I want it to show in the gallery too. How this can be done.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673809/android-picture-saved-to-sd-card-not-showing-in-gallery check this link, you can send broadcast too

Answer (score 0):

There is a little add on in the above code. The above code is saving the pic in the storage. But the Image is not showing in the gallery. To show the image in gallery just need to setup a `MediaScannerConnection` for the bitmap we are saving

**Sample Function**

```
public void scanPhoto(final String imageFileName) {
    MediaScannerConnection msConn = new MediaScannerConnection(PaintPic.this,
            new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                    msConn.scanFile(imageFileName, null);
                    Log.i("msClient obj  in Photo Utility",
                            "connection established");
                }

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    msConn.disconnect();
                    Log.i("msClient obj in Photo Utility", "scan completed");
                }
            });
    msConn.connect();
}
```

and **call** this function just after this line

```
save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
```

Now the saved bitmap is also visible in the `Gallery`