# Android drawing a line to follow your finger and move the line

Tags: android, paint

What I want to do is draw a line that will follow my finger and move that line. I've created a custom view, and I have an onTouchEvent() that works.

I can draw a static line in the onDraw() method without much trouble.

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676311/android-app-how-to-save-a-bitmap-drawing-on-canvas-as-image-check-code/18676403#18676403

Comment: Draw line in a thread .

Comment: @JRowan not this line
 mCanvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, mBitmapPaint);

Comment: use touchdown to store the first x1,y1, and then touchup to store x2,y2 and also on touchup invalidate() after you get the coordinates