# Android videos from a custom folder are not returned by cursor. just 0 rows returned

Tags: android, video, android-cursor, video-gallery

For some reason my cursor in android will not return any video files that are in the folder I'm searching through. If I do minor changes to the code and search for Images instead. The cursor returns all images correctly, so only when I try searching for the videos the issue appears.
Result is count = 0, even though there are several videos in the folder.

I would be greatful for any help I can get.

This is the code snippet I'm using:

```
...
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
String uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
         "MyCameraApp");
String condition = uri + " like '%" + path.toString() + "%'";

cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns,
            condition,
            null //selection args,
            null //orderBy);

count = cursor.getCount();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out i needed to update the Mediastore to get the latest videos to appear when searching through the MediaStore
For an example see [Answer by Jake Basile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673809/android-picture-saved-to-sd-card-not-showing-in-gallery/6673823#6673823)