# Android camera intent file into imageview NPE (SGS3)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-camera

There's lots of questions on the same topic, however none of them provided me an answer.
I've tried a lot of solutions, yet none of them is working for me so far.

I'm invoking the camera intent in a fragment and inserting uri to the newly created file where I want the picture to be stored and then on activityresult I'm passing the uri to a new activity where I want to show it in an imageview and then proceed to upload it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/" + "Camera/" + File.separator+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);
Log.d("camera", "imageUri: " + imageUri.toString());
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERACODE);


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch(requestCode){
case CAMERACODE:{
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubmitActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageuri", imageUri.toString());
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

and in SubmitActivity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
imageUri = extras.getString("imageuri"); <-- imageUri has the correct path, and the actual file is created and the photo is there. The photo is not showing up on gallery for some reason though, only when browsing the folders. What is the reason for this?
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedpicture);
iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri)); <-- this line causes a NullPointerException.
```

Can anyone explain the reason for why the setImageURI fails? Any alternative way of doing this? I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `iv` is null and there is no problem with `imageuri`.
Check whether you have done `setContentView` and check if the layout has `selectedpicture` imageView.

Edit:

```
The photo is not showing up on gallery for some reason though
```

Gallery uses [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) to get all the photos on the sdcard. But when you take a picture `MediaStore` db would not have been updated. For the pic to show up in gallery `MediaScanning` should be run. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107823/force-scan-files-after-taking-photo)

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I had a different ID in the xml file (duh)