# Avoid toast when Media Scanner Complete

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

In my app, I have functions of taking photos and open gallery to watch them.
When user take a photo, it updates media through:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
   Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But always appears saying something like "Media scan completed". 
I would like to remove this toast.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling the toast shown by another process is not possible. You can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107823/force-scan-files-after-taking-photo?rq=1) to force media scan without using broadcast

Comment: It's curious, I tried the solution of this thread in a Samsung Galaxy S2 and a SE Xperia Arc S. In SE perfect but in Galaxy it didn't update media. Only worked with the intent and its corresponding toast :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sendBroadcast` but just for a specific file (in your case the one created after taking the photo). This way you won't get the toast.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(someFile)));
```