# Pictures are not saved in the device

Tags: android, eclipse, image, save

I don't know that I'm doing wrong, everyrthings seems to be ok, but no picture is being saved in the telephone when I press capture.

the message picture has being save appears, but there's nothing on my gallery.

```
package com.mamlambo.mirror;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.mamlambo.mirror.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MirrorActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MirrorActivity";
private Camera mCam;
private MirrorView mCamPreview;
private int mCameraId = 0;
private FrameLayout mPreviewLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera feature on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        mCameraId = findFirstFrontFacingCamera();

        if (mCameraId >= 0) {
            mPreviewLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camPreview);
            mPreviewLayout.removeAllViews();

            startCameraInLayout(mPreviewLayout, mCameraId);

            Button takePic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);
            takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCam.takePicture(null, null, MirrorActivity.this);

                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private int findFirstFrontFacingCamera() {
    int foundId = -1;
    // find the first front facing camera
    int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camId = 0; camId < numCams; camId++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Found front facing camera");
            foundId = camId;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundId;
}

private void startCameraInLayout(FrameLayout layout, int cameraId) {

    // TODO pull this out of the UI thread.
    mCam = Camera.open(cameraId);
    if (mCam != null) {
        mCamPreview = new MirrorView(this, mCam);
        layout.addView(mCamPreview);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mCam == null && mPreviewLayout != null) {
        mPreviewLayout.removeAllViews();
        startCameraInLayout(mPreviewLayout, mCameraId);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mCam != null) {
        mCam.release();
        mCam = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFileDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "SimpleSelfCam");

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't make path to save pic.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    }

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "latest_mug.jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved as latest_mug.jpg",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "File not saved: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't save image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class MirrorView extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MirrorView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,
                    "Error starting mPreviewLayout: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
            int h) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }

        // can't make changes while mPreviewLayout is active
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            // set rotation to match device orientation
            setCameraDisplayOrientationAndSize();

            // start up the mPreviewLayout
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,
                    "Error starting mPreviewLayout: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientationAndSize() {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraId, info);
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = rotation * 90;

        /*
         * // the above is just a shorter way of doing this, but could break
         * if the values change switch (rotation) { case Surface.ROTATION_0:
         * degrees = 0; break; case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90;
         * break; case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break; case
         * Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break; }
         */

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        } else {
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

        Camera.Size previewSize = mCam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        if (result == 90 || result == 270) {
            // swap - the physical camera itself doesn't rotate in relation
            // to the screen ;)
            mHolder.setFixedSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width);
        } else {
            mHolder.setFixedSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

        }
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you isolate the code you think is responsible. There's a lot of code to look at here and some of it is clearly not related to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures do not automatically save to the gallery even if you store them to the correct file directory. To make the pictures appeare in the gallery you need to have the android `MediaScanner` add them. You can access the `MediaScanner` either by `Intent` or with a method/callback that will notify you when the picture has been added. [Here are some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107823/force-scan-files-after-taking-photo) but a seach of S/O should turn up even more results.

Comment: I should add something to my code?

Comment: Yes - take a look at the link I provided along with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270789/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android) - you're basicly going to just run the media scanner in the part of your code where you create a file for the image

Comment: Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(pictureFileDir));
            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

Comment: I added that to the part of "    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {" but still doesnt work

Comment: Look at the examples - if you're correctly getting/creating the file, adding to the media scanner will work. That's the one part your missing - just work on the implementation. I don't know why it's not working beyond that.